# Shadow issue in ie 8 and ie 7 in a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, html

In my website slider on top of the page is not showing properly in ie 7 and ie8 .
shadow is coming in first image not in rest of all images only in ie.Its working fine ie mozilla and other browser.

http://maxrevamp.oliveebusiness.com/hospital-pitampura4.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because IE7 & IE8 don't support css3.

Try css3pie http://css3pie.com/

Comment: So why is coming in first slider image, it is not suppose to come even one slider

Comment: shadow is coming in first image its not coming in rest of all images